# How do I access the full URL of a websocket request inside an elixir phoenix channel?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

In my phoenix channel I need to do some things that requires me to know what domain the request was made for. Example: https://beta.example.com vs https://www.example.com. Is there any way to access that information from or pass that information to a phoenix channel?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to add that to the main page on the initial page, then explicitly pass it when the client pushes the message. I have a number of settings I store on the page. I also have wrappers around the channel push to add those values on each push.

I have not looked into the transport stuff in the socket struct. You could dive into those also. Just inspect the socket and look through each of the fields.